# chekbox vertical-align middle not working in td

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I want the checkbox vertical align middle, and other element vertical align top,but it does not work. I have try to use height:100%, it works well in chrome, but not IE.

html:

```
  <td class="cart_info_td">
      <input type="checkbox" class="cart_info-check">
      <a href="#"><img src="images/dynamic/product.jpg" class="cart_info-pic"></a>
      <a href="#">product's title</a>
  </td>
```

css:

```
.cart_info-check {
    vertical-align: middle;
    //height: 100%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
 }
```

Comment: The vertical-align property applies to a container element, in this case the td. It describes how to align the elements within a container. What is the CSS for cart_info_td?

Comment: table use `table-layout:fixed`;
    `.cart_info_td {
         vertical-align:top;
         width: 400px;
         text-align: left;
     }`

Comment: So all elements within the `td` will have `vertical-align: top`

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this

```css
td {
    text-align: center; 
    vertical-align: top;
}

.cart_info-check {
    text-align: center; 
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="cart_info-check">
      <input type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="#"><img src="images/dynamic/product.jpg" class="cart_info-pic"></a>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="#">product's title</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I hope that helped you